# Right click in windows 10 very slow

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

Since I've upgrade form windows7 to windows10, the right mouse click (context menu) is very slow (3 to 5 seconds) This is on a fast I7 system.
I've already reduced the context entries with "ccleaner" and glary utilities. But still it takes seconds before the context menu appear 
I used to get the context menu instantly.

Any suggestions what to do about this slow right clicks?

Comment: Any context menu or specific context menu?

Comment: Does this happen when right-clicking a particular file type, or everywhere else?

Comment: Please elaborate on what brand and model of computer, what is running in the task bar, what menu is giving you issue (or if it is all of them). There are very specific issues with some PC brands, not just all Windows 10 faults. Have you updated BIOS and drivers to Windows 10 compatible versions?  Have you verified hardware compatibility? Has Windows had a chance to run all the updates?

Comment: may be the registry is fragmented severly